# Application.make in JavaScript for Automation (JXA)

Tags: macos, applescript, javascript-automation

I'm trying to convert this existing AppleScript script:

```
tell application "System Events"
  make login item with properties {path:"/Applications/Application.app", hidden:false"}
end tell
return
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env osascript -l JavaScript

'use strict';

ObjC.import('stdlib')

function run(argv) {

  var systemEvents = Application('System Events')

  systemEvents.make({
    new: 'LoginItem',
    at: systemEvents.loginItems,
    withProperties: {
      name: "Application",
      path: "/Applications/Application.app",
      hidden: false,
      kind: "Programm"
    }
  })

  $.exit(0)
}
```

I am stuck at the following line however, as I don't actually know what to pass to the `new:` property, I *think* the other properties are correct.

```
 new: 'LoginItem',
```

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Make new` doesn't work in **JXA**.

Use `theApp.TheClassName({somePropertyName: "someValue"})` to create object.

After that, use `theApp.theClassNameWith_s.push(theObject)` to append the object to the array

Example:

> ```
> var systemEvents = Application('System Events')
> logItemObj = systemEvents.LoginItem({path: "/Applications/Preview.app", hidden: false})
> systemEvents.loginItems.push(logItemObj)
> ```

- Don't use `kind` and `name`, these properties are read only.

Comment: Thanks. It's a shame that `make` doesn't work, but at least there is a way.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, been working on it for hours as I too had no idea that make didn't work in JXA.

Comment: Is this still the case? I'm trying out the solution with "Database Events" application to create Database, Record, and Field - but I get `Error: AppleEvent handler failed` error.

Comment: If you want to create something in "Database Events", use an **AppleScript** , because  it's impossible to create a new database, a new record or a field from a **JXA** script (bugged).

Answer (score 0):

I can get `make()` to work in JXA with Finder like this:

```js
Application('Finder').make({
  new: 'finderWindow'
});
```

The class name always seems to be camel-cased. What I can't make Finder do is listen to the `target` property, but that seems to be an issue in normal classic AppleScript too.